# how do we retrieve the android versionName value from manifest file using perl script

Tags: perl

I am trying to get the android:versionName from manifest.xml file and set the value as environment variable using Perl script . as i am new to Perl can anyone help on this. 
Here is the my manifest file.

I want to get android:versionName value and set the same value as environment variable using perl script. can you please anyone help on this.

***manifestfile.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; package="com.dev.mobile" android:versionCode="75" android:versionName="1.0.1.68">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />'
```

Comment: here is my manifestfile.xml file '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dev.mobile"
    android:versionCode="75"
    android:versionName="1.0.1.68">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />'

Comment: Please do not ad code to the comments, it is unreadable. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code. If you don't have any code, then Stack Overflow probably isn't the best place for your question.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest for XML, the answer is almost always 'use a parser'.

`XML::Twig` is quite lightweight and simple. (`XML::LibXML` is more fully featured, and is a good alternative).

And to do your thing:

```
#!/perl/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use XML::Twig;

my $xml = XML::Twig -> parsefile ( 'manifestfile.xml');
print $xml -> root -> att('android:versionName'),"\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your use case the below code should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w 
open FP, "manifest.xml"; 
$version=""; 
while (<FP>) 
{ 
    if (( /android:versionName/) && ( /versionName=(.*)\>/ )) 
    { 
        $version=$1; 
        last; 
    } 
} 
print $version;
```

Comment: Please don't recommend parsing XML with regular expressions. It works in this case, but it's a terrible habit to ger into.

Comment: I agree you are right about it. But using extra XML module wasn't deemed necessary for this simple case IMHO.  @DaveCross you are right about it. Will edit it accordingly. Thanks.